# installing gems for ruby with devkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
 GEM CONFIGURATION:
  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - :sources => []
 REMOTE SOURCES:
```

I'm getting this error

```
>PS C:\Windows\system32> gem sources --add https://rubygems.org
Error fetching https://rubygems.org:
        Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_coygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your machine is having some kind of firewalls try to add http://rubygems.org without the ssl.

Comment: how to install multiple gems  using command or any loop @HEraju